# How do I split coordinates using python stored in a list into another array/list of their respective axis components

Tags: python, list

for example, how do i split the list of coordinates:

```
coordinates = [(0.24030250759039373, 0.26361380345416574), (0.4054703969436695, 0.21348000864926886), (0.05345487382386427, 0.2434195883426472)]
```

into

```
xi = (0.2403025075903937, 0.4054703969436695, 0.05345487382386427)
# and 
yi = (0.26361380345416574,0.21348000864926886,0.2434195883426472)
```

using Python without using simple code

I tried doing it with

```
coordinates = [(0.24030250759039373, 0.26361380345416574), (0.4054703969436695, 0.21348000864926886), (0.05345487382386427, 0.2434195883426472)] 
def obj(coordinates):
    for i in range(3):
        # Extract coordinates (xi, yi)
        xi, yi = coords[2*i], coords[2*i+1]
        return (xi, yi)
cord = obj(coords)
print(cord)
# But I could only fetch the first two coordinates, i.e, (0.24030250759039373, 0.26361380345416574), (0.4054703969436695, 0.21348000864926886)
```

Desired output

```
xi = (0.24030250759039373, 0.4054703969436695, 0.05345487382386427)
yi = (0.26361380345416574, 0.21348000864926886, 0.2434195883426472)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `zip()`:

```
xi, yi = zip(*coordinates)
```

or using list comprehensions:

```
xi = tuple([x[0] for x in coordinates])
yi = tuple([x[1] for x in coordinates])
```

or if you still wanted to use the same function:

```
coordinates=[(0.24030250759039373, 0.26361380345416574), (0.4054703969436695, 0.21348000864926886), (0.05345487382386427, 0.2434195883426472)]

def obj(coords):
    xi = []
    yi = []
    for i in range(3):
        xi.append(coords[i][0])
        yi.append(coords[i][1])
    return tuple(xi), tuple(yi)
xi, yi = obj(coordinates)
```

Notes:

1. In your function, the argument name is `coordinates`, but you use coords in the for loop. Probably a bad idea.
2. Return is in the for loop too, so it wouldn't actually go through the whole for loop.
3. Not sure what the `2*i` and `2*i+1` are meant to be?

Comment: No worries :-) glad I could help! If you want to mark it solved I'd appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using *zip()* as proposed by @Mark is the optimum solution.

However, if you insist on writing your own loop you could do this:

```
coordinates = [(0.24030250759039373, 0.26361380345416574), (0.4054703969436695, 0.21348000864926886), (0.05345487382386427, 0.2434195883426472)]

xi = tuple()
yi = tuple()

for x, y in coordinates:
    xi = *xi, x
    yi = *yi, y

print(xi)
print(yi)
```

...or...

```
coordinates = [(0.24030250759039373, 0.26361380345416574), (0.4054703969436695, 0.21348000864926886), (0.05345487382386427, 0.2434195883426472)]

xy = [tuple(), tuple()]

for pair in coordinates:
    for i, v in enumerate(pair):
        xy[i] = *xy[i], v

print(*xy, sep='\n')
```

**Output:**

```
(0.24030250759039373, 0.4054703969436695, 0.05345487382386427)
(0.26361380345416574, 0.21348000864926886, 0.2434195883426472)
```